# Give equal height to children of elements within a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Right now, my orange squares (the children in the flex container) work as intended and they are all the same height, but I can't make it work for the red ones.

I want to make the height of the red items (the children of the children) all have the same height as the highest one.

My HTML is the following:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.col  {
  flex: 1;
  background:orange;
  margin: 1px;
}

.col-item {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="col-item" style="background: red;">
                <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Hello World</p>

          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="col-item" style="background: red;">
              <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>

          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="col-item" style="background: red;">
              <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some other text..</p>
    <p>Some other text..</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flex properties on the parent container (`container` in your example) don't pass down to the child elements, even if they are also containers. Therefore you also need to make the `col` divs `display:flex`, as follows:

```
.col  {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;           /* make this a flex container so it has flex properties */
    justify-content: center; /* to horizontally center them in this flex display */
    /* REST OF YOUR CSS HERE */ 
}
```

Note that you also need to add `flex: 1;` to the content itself so it doesn't shrink, e.g.:

```
.col-item {
    flex: 1;
    /* REST OF YOUR CSS HERE */ 
}
```

**Working Example** with your code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
  margin: 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col-item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-item" style="background: red;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-item" style="background: red;">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-item" style="background: red;">
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
        <p>Some other text..</p>
        <p>Some other text..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use for the inner container the same properties you used in the outer one (display: flex and flex: 1):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.col  {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background:orange;
  margin: 1px;
}

.col-item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="col-item" style="background: red;">
                <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Hello World</p>

          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="col-item" style="background: red;">
              <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>

          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="col-item" style="background: red;">
              <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some other text..</p>
    <p>Some other text..</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```